# Electron app crashing when signed for macOS App Store and deployed via TestFlight in ThreadPoolSingleThreadForegroundBlocking0

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I have an electron application that is very basic based off the [Quick Start tutorial](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start) that simply loads a web page with a link. When I build it with `npm run make` I can test it and it works great.

When I package it up and submit to macOS App Store I can run it via TestFlight and it crashes after startup. I am desperate, I don't know how to proceed. Here is the crash:

```
Crashed Thread:        23  ThreadPoolSingleThreadForegroundBlocking0

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 5 Trace/BPT trap: 5
Terminating Process:   exc handler [27932]
```

Thread 23 looks like this:

```
Thread 23 Crashed:: ThreadPoolSingleThreadForegroundBlocking0
0   Electron Framework                         0x1161fb239 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8381609
1   Electron Framework                         0x1162901bd node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8991789
2   Electron Framework                         0x1162906ac node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8993052
3   Electron Framework                         0x116290313 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8992131
4   Electron Framework                         0x116295248 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 9012408
5   Electron Framework                         0x116294d8e node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 9011198
6   Electron Framework                         0x1159fa9d0 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(v8::internal::Heap*) + 9281152
7   Electron Framework                         0x1155122b9 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(v8::internal::Heap*) + 4134761
8   Electron Framework                         0x116236edd node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8626509
9   Electron Framework                         0x11625dfc6 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8786486
10  Electron Framework                         0x11625e670 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8788192
11  Electron Framework                         0x11625d944 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8784820
12  Electron Framework                         0x11628d257 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8979655
13  Electron Framework                         0x11625d568 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8783832
14  Electron Framework                         0x11626af4d node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8839613
15  Electron Framework                         0x11626ad4d node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8839101
16  Electron Framework                         0x11628d778 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8980968
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib                 0x7ff808c924e1 _pthread_start + 125
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib                 0x7ff808c8df6b thread_start + 15
```

My `package.json` is pretty basic:

```
{
  "name": "electron",
  "productName": "electron test app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test electron app",
  "app-bundle-id": "com.foo.foo-one.electron",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package --platform=mas",
    "make": "electron-forge make"
  },  
  "author": "gordon warren",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.64",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.64",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.64",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.64",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.64",
    "electron": "^19.0.9"
  },  
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0"
  },  
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {
        "appBundleId": "com.foo.foo-one.electron"
      },  
      "makers": [
        {   
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
          "config": {
            "name": "electron"
          }   
        },  
        {   
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          "platforms": [
          "platforms": [
            "darwin"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
          "config": {}
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
          "config": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I am packaging this app as a child in a larger bundle. Therefore, I am signing it myself with a shell script I wrote and have enabled sandbox and inherit entitlements.

I feel fairly certain this is not a code signing issue or entitlement issue because I have run through a number of those and those crashes were all `CODE_SIGNING`. Nevertheless, when I dump the entitlements of the tool:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "https://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key> com.apple.application-identifier</key> <string> XXXXXXXXXX.com.foo.foo-one</string>
<key> com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key> <string> XXXXXXXXXX</string>
<key> com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key> <true/>
<key> com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
<array>
<string>
367LHY3NY2.com.foo.foo-one.electron</string>
<string>
group.com.foo.one</string>
</array>
<key> com.apple.security.automation.apple-events</key> <true/>
<key> com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key> <true/>
<key> com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key> <true/>
<key> com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key> <true/>
<key> com.apple.security.device.audio-input</key> <true/>
<key> com.apple.security.device.bluetooth</key> <true/>
<key> com.apple.security.device.camera</key> <true/>
<key> com.apple.security.network.client</key> <true/>
<key> com.apple.security.network.server</key> <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Here is the entire crash report (if necessary):

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               electron test app [27932]
Path:                  /Applications/foo.app/Contents/MacOS/electron test app.app/Contents/MacOS/electron test app
Identifier:            com.foo.foo-one.electron
Version:               1.2.1 (24)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        foo [27894]
Responsible:           foo [27894]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2022-07-25 16:26:55.6238 -0400
OS Version:            macOS 12.4 (21F79)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     6.5 (19P5071)
Anonymous UUID:        

Sleep/Wake UUID:       B316D3DF-2FE2-484D-B9B6-86BCAA072FB9

Time Awake Since Boot: 75000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       31782 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        23  ThreadPoolSingleThreadForegroundBlocking0

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 5 Trace/BPT trap: 5
Terminating Process:   exc handler [27932]

Thread 0:: CrBrowserMain Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   Electron Framework                     0x1156ea8e0 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(v8::internal::Heap*) + 6069648
1   Electron Framework                     0x1154d48e2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(v8::internal::Heap*) + 3882386
2   Electron Framework                     0x1154d3513 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(v8::internal::Heap*) + 3877315
3   Electron Framework                     0x1154d2fca v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(v8::internal::Heap*) + 3875962
4   Electron Framework                     0x115932666 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(v8::internal::Heap*) + 8461078
5   Electron Framework                     0x1154d2ca4 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(v8::internal::Heap*) + 3875156
6   Electron Framework                     0x1154d52f0 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(v8::internal::Heap*) + 3884960
7   Electron Framework                     0x1154d155d v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(v8::internal::Heap*) + 3869197
8   Electron Framework                     0x113604611 v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock::set_loop_header(v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock*) + 15681
9   Electron Framework                     0x11360574e v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock::set_loop_header(v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock*) + 20094
10  Electron Framework                     0x11360523f v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock::set_loop_header(v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock*) + 18799
11  Electron Framework                     0x113604094 v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock::set_loop_header(v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock*) + 14276
12  Electron Framework                     0x1136041b6 v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock::set_loop_header(v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock*) + 14566
13  Electron Framework                     0x113347148 ElectronMain + 152
14  dyld                                   0x10a83151e start + 462

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c8df48 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c8df48 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c8df48 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c8df48 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c8df48 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c8df48 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:: ThreadPoolServiceThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff808c5e8ca kevent64 + 10
1   Electron Framework                     0x1162a0803 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 9058931
2   Electron Framework                     0x1162566ea node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8755546
3   Electron Framework                     0x11622003f node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8532655
4   Electron Framework                     0x116271248 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8864952
5   Electron Framework                     0x11625b68d node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8775933
6   Electron Framework                     0x1162713dd node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8865357
7   Electron Framework                     0x11628d778 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8980968
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c924e1 _pthread_start + 125
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c8df6b thread_start + 15

Thread 8:: ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff808c5597a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff808c55ce8 mach_msg + 56
2   Electron Framework                     0x116299588 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 9029624
3   Electron Framework                     0x11626a6de node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8837454
4   Electron Framework                     0x11626b04c node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8839868
5   Electron Framework                     0x11626aced node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8839005
6   Electron Framework                     0x11628d778 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8980968
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c924e1 _pthread_start + 125
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c8df6b thread_start + 15

Thread 9:: ThreadPoolBackgroundWorker
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff808c5597a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff808c55ce8 mach_msg + 56
2   Electron Framework                     0x116299588 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 9029624
3   Electron Framework                     0x11626a6de node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8837454
4   Electron Framework                     0x11626ae2f node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8839327
5   Electron Framework                     0x11626ac5d node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8838861
6   Electron Framework                     0x11628d778 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8980968
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c924e1 _pthread_start + 125
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c8df6b thread_start + 15

Thread 10:: ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff808c5597a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff808c55ce8 mach_msg + 56
2   Electron Framework                     0x116299588 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 9029624
3   Electron Framework                     0x11626a6de node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8837454
4   Electron Framework                     0x11626b04c node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8839868
5   Electron Framework                     0x11626aced node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8839005
6   Electron Framework                     0x11628d778 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8980968
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c924e1 _pthread_start + 125
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c8df6b thread_start + 15

Thread 11:: Chrome_IOThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff808c5e8ca kevent64 + 10
1   Electron Framework                     0x1162a0803 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 9058931
2   Electron Framework                     0x1162566ea node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8755546
3   Electron Framework                     0x11622003f node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8532655
4   Electron Framework                     0x116271248 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8864952
5   Electron Framework                     0x1154d68df v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(v8::internal::Heap*) + 3890575
6   Electron Framework                     0x1162713dd node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8865357
7   Electron Framework                     0x11628d778 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8980968
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c924e1 _pthread_start + 125
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c8df6b thread_start + 15

Thread 12:: MemoryInfra
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff808c5597a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff808c55ce8 mach_msg + 56
2   Electron Framework                     0x116299588 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 9029624
3   Electron Framework                     0x11629941e node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 9029262
4   Electron Framework                     0x1162012b7 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8406311
5   Electron Framework                     0x1162566ea node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8755546
6   Electron Framework                     0x11622003f node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8532655
7   Electron Framework                     0x116271248 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8864952
8   Electron Framework                     0x1162713dd node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8865357
9   Electron Framework                     0x11628d778 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8980968
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c924e1 _pthread_start + 125
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c8df6b thread_start + 15

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff808c5a34e kevent + 10
1   Electron Framework                     0x1133466db uv_free_interface_addresses + 1323
2   Electron Framework                     0x113334ae0 uv_run + 320
3   Electron Framework                     0x1199c825f node::CommonEnvironmentSetup::context() const + 175199
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c924e1 _pthread_start + 125
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c8df6b thread_start + 15

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff808c583ea __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c92a6f _pthread_cond_wait + 1249
2   Electron Framework                     0x1133412e9 uv_cond_wait + 9
3   Electron Framework                     0x1199c8422 node::CommonEnvironmentSetup::context() const + 175650
4   Electron Framework                     0x1199c5eb0 node::CommonEnvironmentSetup::context() const + 166064
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c924e1 _pthread_start + 125
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c8df6b thread_start + 15

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff808c583ea __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c92a6f _pthread_cond_wait + 1249
2   Electron Framework                     0x1133412e9 uv_cond_wait + 9
3   Electron Framework                     0x1199c8422 node::CommonEnvironmentSetup::context() const + 175650
4   Electron Framework                     0x1199c5eb0 node::CommonEnvironmentSetup::context() const + 166064
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c924e1 _pthread_start + 125
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c8df6b thread_start + 15

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff808c583ea __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c92a6f _pthread_cond_wait + 1249
2   Electron Framework                     0x1133412e9 uv_cond_wait + 9
3   Electron Framework                     0x1199c8422 node::CommonEnvironmentSetup::context() const + 175650
4   Electron Framework                     0x1199c5eb0 node::CommonEnvironmentSetup::context() const + 166064
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c924e1 _pthread_start + 125
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c8df6b thread_start + 15

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff808c559b6 semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   Electron Framework                     0x1133418f0 uv_sem_wait + 16
2   Electron Framework                     0x119a3b33d node::SetTracingController(v8::TracingController*) + 52301
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c924e1 _pthread_start + 125
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c8df6b thread_start + 15

Thread 18:: NetworkConfigWatcher
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff808c5597a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff808c55ce8 mach_msg + 56
2   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff808d5938d __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 319
3   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff808d57a18 __CFRunLoopRun + 1276
4   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff808d56e5c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 562
5   Foundation                          0x7ff809bbad6a -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 216
6   Electron Framework                     0x11629352e node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 9004958
7   Electron Framework                     0x116291fa1 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8999441
8   Electron Framework                     0x1162566ea node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8755546
9   Electron Framework                     0x11622003f node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8532655
10  Electron Framework                     0x116271248 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8864952
11  Electron Framework                     0x1162713dd node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8865357
12  Electron Framework                     0x11628d778 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8980968
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c924e1 _pthread_start + 125
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c8df6b thread_start + 15

Thread 19:: CrShutdownDetector
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff808c563ba read + 10
1   Electron Framework                     0x1134efae6 v8::CodeEvent::GetFunctionName() + 23158
2   Electron Framework                     0x11628d778 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8980968
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c924e1 _pthread_start + 125
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c8df6b thread_start + 15

Thread 20:: NetworkConfigWatcher
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff808c5597a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff808c55ce8 mach_msg + 56
2   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff808d5938d __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 319
3   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff808d57a18 __CFRunLoopRun + 1276
4   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff808d56e5c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 562
5   Foundation                          0x7ff809bbad6a -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 216
6   Electron Framework                     0x11629352e node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 9004958
7   Electron Framework                     0x116291fa1 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8999441
8   Electron Framework                     0x1162566ea node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8755546
9   Electron Framework                     0x11622003f node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8532655
10  Electron Framework                     0x116271248 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8864952
11  Electron Framework                     0x1162713dd node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8865357
12  Electron Framework                     0x11628d778 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8980968
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c924e1 _pthread_start + 125
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c8df6b thread_start + 15

Thread 21:: ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff808c5597a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff808c55ce8 mach_msg + 56
2   Electron Framework                     0x116299588 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 9029624
3   Electron Framework                     0x11626a6de node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8837454
4   Electron Framework                     0x11626b04c node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8839868
5   Electron Framework                     0x11626aced node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8839005
6   Electron Framework                     0x11628d778 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8980968
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c924e1 _pthread_start + 125
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c8df6b thread_start + 15

Thread 22:: ThreadPoolForegroundWorker
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff808c5597a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff808c55ce8 mach_msg + 56
2   Electron Framework                     0x116299588 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 9029624
3   Electron Framework                     0x11626a6de node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8837454
4   Electron Framework                     0x11626ae2f node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8839327
5   Electron Framework                     0x11626aced node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8839005
6   Electron Framework                     0x11628d778 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8980968
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c924e1 _pthread_start + 125
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c8df6b thread_start + 15

Thread 23 Crashed:: ThreadPoolSingleThreadForegroundBlocking0
0   Electron Framework                     0x1161fb239 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8381609
1   Electron Framework                     0x1162901bd node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8991789
2   Electron Framework                     0x1162906ac node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8993052
3   Electron Framework                     0x116290313 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8992131
4   Electron Framework                     0x116295248 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 9012408
5   Electron Framework                     0x116294d8e node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 9011198
6   Electron Framework                     0x1159fa9d0 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(v8::internal::Heap*) + 9281152
7   Electron Framework                     0x1155122b9 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap(v8::internal::Heap*) + 4134761
8   Electron Framework                     0x116236edd node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8626509
9   Electron Framework                     0x11625dfc6 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8786486
10  Electron Framework                     0x11625e670 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8788192
11  Electron Framework                     0x11625d944 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8784820
12  Electron Framework                     0x11628d257 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8979655
13  Electron Framework                     0x11625d568 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8783832
14  Electron Framework                     0x11626af4d node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8839613
15  Electron Framework                     0x11626ad4d node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8839101
16  Electron Framework                     0x11628d778 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8980968
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c924e1 _pthread_start + 125
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c8df6b thread_start + 15

Thread 24:: CompositorTileWorker1
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff808c583ea __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c92a6f _pthread_cond_wait + 1249
2   Electron Framework                     0x11628cbfb node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8978027
3   Electron Framework                     0x1171a4403 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 24802931
4   Electron Framework                     0x11628d778 node::AsyncResource::get_async_id() const + 8980968
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c924e1 _pthread_start + 125
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff808c8df6b thread_start + 15


Thread 23 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x000000011b31b558  rbx: 0x000070000dc52ff0  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x000000011b2b2870  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x000070000dc534c0  rsp: 0x000070000dc52f70
   r8: 0x00000000000b29c5   r9: 0xffffffff00000000  r10: 0x000000011b2b2888  r11: 0x0000000000000202
  r12: 0x000070000dc53548  r13: 0x000070000dc52fd1  r14: 0x00006000029781a0  r15: 0x000070000dc53548
  rip: 0x00000001161fb239  rfl: 0x0000000000000246  cr2: 0x00000001161fb238
  
Logical CPU:     1
Error Code:      0x00000000 
Trap Number:     3
```

Comment: @KunalShah no and as soon as we can migrate away from electron we are.

Comment: Having a similar problem, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @julipode My understanding is that it's not possible to test builds built for the MAS. It makes no sense as a developer. I have to submit a build to Apple that I can't actually physically test first? I hate electron.